# Why magento use xml version 1.0

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, xml, configuration

An new interesting has been seen in magento all xml file are  starting with below code-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

My question , **why magento used  `xml version 1.0`?**

why it does not used other  version?

Comment: XML v1 does everything Magento needs. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883084/what-xml-version-to-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML Version 1.0 is the most common one.

There is also XML Version 1.1. available. This version includes some special features but is rarely used. It is recommended if its unique features are needed.

Link:
[Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)